# How do you memorize Abel and Dirichlet convergence criterions?

Tags: calculus, soft-question, improper-integrals, uniform-convergence

I have an exam next week and I'm not going to be able to bring any piece of paper with me. I need to memorize these theorems, both for improper integrals and for function series. How do I go about this? They have quite a lot of conditions and I can never remember which condition goes with the other as the theorems are pretty similar. Do you know them by heart? Is there any logic I could apply?

Comment: 1) work through and learn their proofs
2) apply the theorems to lots of examples
3) learn some counterexamples where the hypothesis and conclusion fail.

In my opinion internalizing these ideas is not about memorization but about experience.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with [Umberto P.](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/67536/umberto-p). I doubt that you’ll be able to find a trick for memorizing those theorems. The best way is to understand again and again their proves.

The key element in the proves is [summation by parts](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation_by_parts). So learn to do summations by parts and the way to use those and you’ll have done real progresses. Learning tricks, tests by heart won’t help to make real progress.